# mysterious variable failure in Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6, alert, uialertview

I been attempting to use some `JSSAlertViews` but for some reason they will not show up either on my simulator or device. I put some breakpoints where I call the alert views and with a little digging came across this in the Alert Views stack :

[image]

what does this mean? Is it the reason for the alert views not showing up and how do I fix it?

Comment: are you displaying it on the main thread?

Comment: yes, I've used the `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue())` method to display it, but no luck. @Max_Power89